# Why social-likes does not auto update counters after share(or likes)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, social-likes

Im using  [social-likes](https://github.com/sapegin/social-likes) plugin to make function "SNS sharing" in my website.

It works well. But it seem to be not update counters after share.(You must  reload page to see new counters)

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
$('#share2').socialLikes({
    forceUpdate: true
});
```

[Advanced Configuration Social-Likes](https://github.com/sapegin/social-likes#refreshing-counters)

Comment: @tR4xXI just write like this

`$('.social-likes').socialLikes({
    url: myurl,
    counters: true,
   zeroes: true
});`

am I missing something?

Comment: you don't use `forceUpdate: true` . I don't know if this will work, because i haven't worked with social-likes yet but i'm pretty sure this is the feature you're looking for.